# How to preselect Section in knockout-postbox.js so that the content is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

After looking into Ryan Niemeyer's brilliant [knockout-postbox.js](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) 
I made some minor adapting and want the menu to open with a preselected section. Hence I added a variable to the initialization of the `selectedSection` observable as seen below.

```
var MenuModel = function() {

    var preselected = "Profile";
    this.name = ko.observable().subscribeTo("nickName");
    this.sections = ["Profile", "Notifications","Users","Projects"];
    this.selectedSection = ko.observable(preselected).publishOn("section");
};
```

This selects the desirable section, however the contents of the section remains invisible.

Here's the preselected sections viewModel:

```
var ProfileModel = function() {
    //apply a filter to turn the value that we receive into a boolean
    this.visible = ko.observable().subscribeTo("section", function(newValue) {
        return newValue === "Profile";
    });

   //some more code - syncing and subscribing/publishing observables.
};
```

The HTML goes like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <h2><span data-bind="text: name"></span>'s Settings</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-bind="foreach: sections">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $root.selectedSection() === $data }">
            <a href="#self" data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.selectedSection"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="profile" data-bind="visible: visible">
    <h3>Profile</h3>
    <label>Nick name: <input id="nick" data-bind="value: nickName" /> </label>
    <label>Email: <input data-bind="value: emailAddress" /></label>
</div>
```

The question is, how can I trigger the `visible` observable of the `ProfileModel` with a preselected setting of `MenuModel`'s `selectedSection` observable, such that the contents are shown?

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/b6gwn6ak/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subscribeTo` helper can take a boolean as a second argument to indicate that you want to initialize it using the last published value. Your compare function can then be passed as the third arg. It would look like:

```
//apply a filter to turn the value that we receive into a boolean
this.visible = ko.observable().subscribeTo("section", true, function(newValue) {
    return newValue === "Profile";
});
```